# ImportError: No module named myapp_o.urls

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I have a django-oscar project I am working on. And I have been searching everywhere to solve this problem. Although, I have come across similiar questions here, I still can't solve the problem.

I am trying to create other pages such as 'about', and 'contacts'. I have checked the dashboard for pages creating but can't seem to do exact what I want. I want to be able put these pages on the footer area. I was able to display these pages created at the dashboard to my footer but it seems simple displaying just text. Was wondering if I could do more.

I have created an app in my apps folder.  Here is the folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

[image: Full folder structure]

Here is my env installs -

pip freeze requirements.txt

```
    Babel==2.3.4<
    beautifulsoup4==4.5.1
    colorama==0.3.7
    coverage==3.7.1
    coveralls==0.4.4
    detox==0.10.0
    Django==1.9.12
    django-appconf==1.0.2
    django-compressor==1.6
    django-countries==4.0
    django-debug-toolbar==1.5
    django-extra-views==0.6.4
    django-haystack==2.5.1
    django-localflavor==1.3
    django-nose==1.4.2
    django-oscar==1.3
    -e git://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar-      paypal.git@76542cefa67170b10694ab431a0b35408d99b16e#egg=django_oscar_paypal
   django-static-precompiler==1.5
   django-tables2==1.0.7
   django-treebeard==4.1.0
   django-webtest==1.7.7
   django-widget-tweaks==1.4.1
   docopt==0.6.2
   enum-compat==0.0.2
   enum34==1.1.6
   eventlet==0.20.0
   factory-boy==2.7.0
   fake-factory==0.7.2
   flake8==2.2.3
   funcsigs==1.0.2
   greenlet==0.4.11
   ipaddress==1.0.17
   mccabe==0.5.2
   mock==1.0.1
   mod-wsgi==4.5.11
   nose==1.3.7
   pbr==1.10.0
   pep8==1.7.0
   phonenumbers==7.7.5
   Pillow==3.4.2
   pinocchio==0.4.1
   pluggy==0.3.1
   purl==1.3
   py==1.4.31
   pycountry==16.11.27.1
   pyflakes==1.3.0
   pytest==3.0.1
   pytest-cov==2.3.1
   pytest-django==3.0.0
   python-dateutil==2.6.0
   pytz==2016.10
   PyYAML==3.12
   requests==2.12.3
   six==1.10.0
   sorl-thumbnail==12.4a1
   sqlparse==0.2.2
   tox==2.1.0
   Unidecode==0.4.19
   virtualenv==15.1.0
   waitress==1.0.1
   WebOb==1.6.3
   WebTest==2.0.16`
```

Here is myapp views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


def about(request):
   return HttpResponse(request, "my about page", {})

def contacts(request):
   return HttpResponse(request, "my contact page", {})
```

Here is apps.myapp urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns`

from . import views
from apps.myapp import views



urlpatterns = patterns ('',
  url(r'^en-gb/contacts/', views.contacts, name='contacts'),
  url(r'^/about/', views.about, name='about'),

)
```

here is mysite (root) urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from apps.app import application
from paypal.payflow.dashboard.app import application as payflow
from paypal.express.dashboard.app import application as express_dashboard
admin.autodiscover()

from apps.app import myapp_o



 '''everything else has to have the include apart from the admin'''

 urlpatterns = patterns
 [
   '',
   (r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
   url(r'^myapp_o/', include('apps.myapp_o.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
  # PayPal Express integration...
  (r'^checkout/paypal/', include('paypal.express.urls')),
  # Dashboard views for Payflow Pro
  (r'^dashboard/paypal/payflow/', include(payflow.urls)),
  # Dashboard views for Express
  (r'^dashboard/paypal/express/', include(express_dashboard.urls)),
  (r'', include(application.urls)),
  '''(r'^myapp_o/', include('myapp_o.urls')),'''

  )

 if settings.DEBUG:
   urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
   urlpatterns += static(
      settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Could anyone share and tell me where I am going wrong?  Or is there a better was of doing this within the dashboard?

Thanks

Eve

Need to add information from my setting

import os

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mod_wsgi.server',
    # External apps
    # 1.5.7 still ships with South migrations in the wrong folder,
    # 1.5.8 contains a fix. Upgrade when released.
    # 'django_extensions',
   'debug_toolbar',
    # Apps from oscar
   'paypal',
   'compressor',
   'widget_tweaks',

   ]



from oscar import get_core_apps
INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + get_core_apps([
    'apps.shipping',
    'apps.checkout',
    'apps.myapp',])
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check your code first:

on `apps/myapp/urls.py`, you should NOT import like this.

```
from . import views
from apps.myapp import views
```

Because later `views` overrides first `views` var. so your code should be changed with `from . import views` or `from views import about, contacts` to get clear import.

Second, after Django 1.8, `urlpatterns` does not use `patterns` anymore. you should consider to use `url` function to use your code after Django1.10(after 1.10 `patterns` is deprecated).

so your code can be changed like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^en-gb/contacts/$', views.contacts, name='contacts'),
  url(r'^about/$', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

I also add `$` end of your url to exactly match url from user's request.

Third, when I searched django docs with [`i18n_patterns`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#language-prefix-in-url-patterns),

You can use django's `urls` with `String` include like `include('paypal.express.urls')`.

I think your urls can be like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^myapp_o/', include('apps.myapp_o.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
  # PayPal Express integration...
  url(r'^checkout/paypal/', include('paypal.express.urls')),
  # Dashboard views for Payflow Pro
  url(r'^dashboard/paypal/payflow/', include(payflow.urls)),
  # Dashboard views for Express
  url(r'^dashboard/paypal/express/', include(express_dashboard.urls)),
  url(r'', include('apps.myapp_o.urls')),    
  )
```

Remember you do not have to import views from app while you're using string import.
Comment if this thing doesn't work.

Comment: I still have the same error unless I comment it out

Comment: In the root mysite url.py                                                                        urlpatterns =[
         url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
         url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
        #url(r'^myapp_o/', include('apps.myapp_o.urls')),
]

Comment: urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    # PayPal Express integration...
    url(r'^checkout/paypal/', include('paypal.express.urls')),
    # Dashboard views for Payflow Pro
    url(r'^dashboard/paypal/payflow/', include(payflow.urls)),
    # Dashboard views for Express
    url(r'^dashboard/paypal/express/', include(express_dashboard.urls)),
    url(r'', include(application.urls)),
    #url(r'^myapp_o/', include('myapp_o.urls')),
)

Comment: here is the error again.  ImportError: No module named myapp_o.urls

Comment: Thank you. I have found an even easy way to do this under the dashboard, Content, and Pages. But I did learnt a let from your code.

Comment: You have no application called 'myapp_o', when you are using include with string. Use include('myapp.urls') to fix ImportError.